# Angular5 pass DOM object to ng-content

Tags: scroll, angular5, ag-grid

I'm newest in web.

I want customize default scroll-bar in ag-grid. I try use *ngx-scrollbar* for this. In sources *ngx-scrollbar* I found that *ngx-scrollbar* using *ng-content* for wrapping elements([link to github source file](https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-scrollbar/blob/master/projects/ngx-scrollbar/src/lib/scrollbar.component.html)). If wrap *ag-grid-angular* element then scrolling even doesn't shows because content doesn't overflow *ag-grid-angular* content because oveflow happen in *div* with class *.ag-body-viewport* where using stock srolls. In order to achieve needed effect I wish pass DOM element with class *.ag-body-viewport* to *ng-content* of *ngx-scrollbar*. Is it possible?

More info here [github issue](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/958) but I don't use Nice Scroll or Perfect Scrollbar

I want use *ngx-scrollbar* because it has capability of customization.

**UPDATE**

I can pass DOM element to *ng-content* using next sintax(agGridViewport is native element):

```
<ng-scrollbar>
    {{ agGridViewport }}
<ng-scrollbar>
```

but it pass element like a copy of real DOM object but I want pass this like a refence.

Now I got UI like a stack style:

[rendered real ag-grid-angular]
[rendered ng-scrollbar with his content]

But it isn't that I need. Also I got bad rendering with artifacts and even some components doesn't appear. Now I want to try use Renderer2 for putting *ng-scrollbar* element between two DOM elements in tree(*.ag-body-viewport*-wrapper and *.ag-body-viewport*). But I think it's very bad idea because Renderer2 doesn't have methods for putting elements between DOM elements in tree and my code will be very unlify and complicated :( It's must be like injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I can not do injection in DOM with Angular tools. It's bad idea do it and it is not possible now. AgGrid doesn't support customization with tools like *ngx-scrollbar* which using *ng-content* for wrapping components and other elements. May be better way using other tools which working by another way or using webkit customization which supports not all web browsers.

UPDATE

Also I try to use [smooth-scrollbar](https://github.com/idiotWu/smooth-scrollbar). I managed to get better result. I bind him to element *.ag-body-viewport*. It works fine but it scrolling only content of grid without header be careful. *smooth-scroll* bar doesn't have options for horizontal and vertical scrollbar as a different units. I know how issue can be solve. Vertical scrollbar must be bind to *.ag-body-viewport* and horizaontal scrollbar must be bind to *.ag-root*. If your can find scrollbar which let you do it that you can solve this problem. May be I write special component for Angular in near future and then add link to this answer. If you do it faster you can add yourself link or you can add link to already existing packages.